# Is there any benefit to tagging my class's constructor(s) as [[nodiscard]] when the class itself is tagged as [[nodiscard]]?

Tags: c++, c++17, nodiscard, c++-attributes

Say I have this class:

```
class [[nodiscard]] MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() : _x(x) {}
   MyClass(int x) : _x(x) {}

private:
   int _x;
};
```

Does adding the `[[nodiscard]]` tag individually to the class's constructors change anything?  Or is that wholly redundant with the `[[nodiscard]]` tag applied to the class declaration itself, and therefore only adds unnecessary noise to the header file?

(My testing suggests the later, but I might be missing some nuance)

Comment: Note that there is a point to marking a constructor as `nodiscard`. However, this case (an explicit conversion that calls that constructor) is also covered by marking the type `nodiscard`.

Comment: To mark a type as `[[nodiscard]]` (opposed to just its constructors) should be done with care. It can hinder others when writing setter-like functions that typically would be `void`, but intended to return your type as a courtesy (for sake of convience/not wasting some already done work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking the individual constructors as `[[nodiscard]]` is completely redundant and unnecessary if the class as a whole is marked as `[[nodiscard]]`.